# Can a gas giant form in the Goldilocks zone and have habitable moons. And if it can how many of those moons could be habitable?

Tags: planets, space, aliens, moons, habitability

Humanity is about to leave our solar system for some reason and a gas giant with 60 moons has been spotted in the Goldilocks zone of a nearby solar system. They arrive there and it turns out, a space-fairing community has already developed.

Firstly, could a Jupiter-like planet form in the Goldilocks zone? Secondly, could a few of its moons be able to support life? Thirdly, could advanced, space-faring life evolve separately on at least 4 of the moons? Fourthly, would they be friendly to our earthlings? And finally, what might society and culture be like?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding @Gnorsk. Regarding points 4 and 5... if they are friendly or not, and what the society would be life, is entirely up to you as the author. 3 is kind of broad and up to you as well. For point 2: define "life".

Comment: For approachable information on what we’ve learned about the formation of planets and wnere they wind up, peruse the [SETI Colloquium series](http://www.seti.org/seti-institute/about-seti/weekly-lectures/archives/2016).  This is a common subject that is covered with current findings!

Comment: The various questions are already answered. http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/17766/885  http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4729/is-a-jupiter-sized-planet-plausible-in-a-habitable-zone/15338#15338  and http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21542/is-it-statistically-and-physically-possible-to-have-two-civilizations-in-the-sam/21561#21561 that I recall working on…many others.  Use the Search!

Comment: I don't think you could have 60 moons in stable orbits around a single planet...

Comment: @Annonymus tell that to Saturn. Moons do not have to be large and spherical. A bunch of 10km rocks could also constitute 60 moons. They won't be inhabitable, but that was not the question.